# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Singular Imperativ mit und ohne 'e' am Ende?

Tags: verb, imperative

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Singular Imperativ mit und ohne 'e' am Ende?

Zum Beispiel:

> - „Geh(e) weiter!“
> - „Hab(e) Geduld!“

Bedeutet „Geh“ etwas anderes als „Gehe“?

Darf man „e“ am Ende jeden Verbs hinzufügen oder weglassen?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Was die **Bedeutung** der beiden Varianten beim Imperativ Singular betrifft, gibt es zwischen den beiden Formen **keinen Unterschied.**

Im Sprachgebrauch ist die Endung -e meistens fakultativ: *geh!* und *gehe!* oder *ruf!* und *rufe!* sind gleichwertige Parallelformen. Bei schwachen Verben, deren Wortstamm auf `-t` oder `-d` endet, gilt die Form mit `-e` als stilistisch besser: *bete!* und *rede!* klingen besser als *bet!* und *red!*.

Bei Verben wie *rechnen* oder *atmen*, bei denen aus dem Wortstamm ein `e` entfällt (siehe Rechen(-regel), Atem) ist die Imperativform mit der Endung `-e`, also *rechne!*, die einzig mögliche Variante.

Bei Verben auf `-eln` und `-ern` muss zum Wortstamm ohne die Endung `-st` ebenfalls ein `-e` angefügt werden: *wandere!*; bei den Verben auf `-eln` kann außerdem das `e` im Wortstamm entfallen: *sammele!* oder *sammle!*

Starke Verben mit Vokalwechsel im Imperativ können kein -e als Endung bekommen, es heißt nur: *wirf!*, *gib!*, *iss!*.

Quelle: [Wikipedia-Artikel zum deutschen Imperativ](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperativ_%28Modus%29)

Answer (score 5):

Splattne has already provided [an excellent answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-singular-imperativ-mit-und-ohne-e-am-ende/3107#3107), so let me add some practical observations:

This may be specific to Berlin lower classes, but some people use wrong regular imperatives when an irregular form would be correct: *sehe!* instead of the correct *sieh!*

It seems to me that sometimes the form with -e is seen as stronger than the form without (probably by the same people who make the above mistake):

> *Jaqueline, sehe es endlich ein!*
>   *Kevin, gehe in dein Zimmer!*

Comment: Ja, ja, die niederen Stände!

Answer (score 0):

Gut, man kann Vorbehalte gegen die Aristrokatie haben aber daraus Grammatikregeln zu basteln erscheint mir fragwuerdig. In solchen Faellen waere eine Quellenangabe vertrauenswuerdiger und nachvollziehbarer.
Schauen Sie einfach mal bei Helbig/Buscha  "Deutsche Grammatik" Seite 193-194

Imperativ

1. Das die  Singularform kennzeichnende "e" entfaellt obligatorisch (nur bei sehen ist es fakultativ: Sieh(e)
2. das "e" steht nur bei Singularformen von Verben, deren Stamm
   auf -ig
   auf eine schwer aussprechbare Konsonanatenverbindung
   auf t oder d
   endet

Bsp. Entschuldige, Antworte, Lande, Atme, Widme, Oeffne, Rede, Biete

3. Das "e" ist obligatorisch bei Verben auf -eln und -ern
   Das e des Suffix entfaellt bei Verben der Endung -eln, bei Verben der Endung -ern kann das Suffix e sowohl weggelassen als auch geschrieben werden. (ohne e ist es umgangssprachlich)
   Bsp.
   Schüttle, Bummle, Lächle, Kich(e)re, Zwink(e)re, Klapp(e)re

Das nur mal meine 10 Cent
Frank

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Ich kann aus der Frage keinerlei Aristokratie-Hinweise erkennen. SE funktioniert anders als ein Forum: hier gibt es keine aufeinander aufbauenden "Meinungen", sondern jede Antwort steht idR für sich alleine in Bezug zur Frage. Daher schlage ich vor: einkürzen und/oder umformulieren. https://german.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score -2):

Ok zweieinhalb Jahre zu spät, und es gibt tatsächlich keinen inhaltlichen Untwrschied, aber das Grundproblem taucht im täglichen Sprach(ge)missbrauch mitlerweile immer häufiger auf, und es fehlt beiden vorhergehenden Ausführungen die wichtigste Grundregel:

Der Imperativ Singular wird aus der 2.Person Singular des betreffenden Verbes hergeleitet, indem einfach "st" weggelassen wird:
"Du siehst"  ...wird zu. "Sieh hin!"  ...und nicht "sehe hin".
Mit dieser Regel erklären sich auch ganz einfach die etwas kompliziert und damit tendenziell interpretationsoffenen "d"-, "t"-, "eln", etc. -Regeln.

Es heisst "bete" und "rede" nicht weil es ein schwaches Verb auf "d" oder "t" oder ist sondern ganz einfach weil die 2.Pers.sing. minus "st" so lautet:
"Du redest" minus "st" ergibt "rede".
"Du betest" minus "st" ergibt "bete".
Analog sieht das bei "sammeln" etc. aus
"Du sammelst das auf." ergibt korrekterweise "Sammel das auf!"  ...und nur, wenn man selber unsicher ist "sammele" oder "sammle".

Ähnlich verhält es sich mit den starken Verben, die kein "e" bilden können:
werfen - du wirfst - wirf    ...und nicht "werfe" oder gar "wirfe".

Wenn man jetzt noch ein paar Grundregeln zu den Umlauten starker Verben beachtet, dann stellt man fest, dass es gar kein "kann man mal mit oder ohne "e" sagen" gibt, sonden dass dies eine extrem zuverlässige Regel ist.
"Du läufst" wird zu "Lauf"  ...und nicht "laufe"...brrrrrrr da schüttelt es einen.
"Du gräbst die Grube." wird zu "Grab die Grube!"
"Du liest das Buch." ...muss ja streng semantisch gesehen "Du liesst das Buch." heissen     ...wird zu "Lies das Buch".
"Du wäscht die Wäsche." wird zu "Wasch die Wäsche!"   und nicht etwa "Wasche!"

Kein inhaltlicher Unterschied also zwischen Imperativ mit oder ohne "e" ausser, dass mit "e" aufgrund des pseudointellektuellen Anstriches sich durchzusetzen droht. "Sitze still und löffele Deine Suppe!" wird man in aristokratischen Kreisen häufiger hören als die Version ohne "e" ...besser wird es dadurch auch nicht!

Comment: Die Aristokratie ist abgeschafft.