# Bleibe Ruhig - Der Erlkönig

Tags: grammaticality, lyrics, imperative

Refering to the Lied [Der Erlkönig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlk%C3%B6nig_(Goethe)) by *Goethe*, the expression *"Bleibe ruhig!"* appears in the fourth stanza. Shouldn't the *Du-form* of the verb *Bleiben* in the imperative be *Bleib* instead of *Bleibe*?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think it should be _Bleib_, since [both versions are correct](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bleiben) (in modern German)?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3106

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The imperative of the verb *bleiben* for the second person singular is *bleib* or *bleibe*. Thus, the expression "Bleibe ruhig!" is correct.