# Meaning of: "Bitte, erinnere mich an … "

Tags: imperative

In imperative:

> Erinnere mich an die Arbeit!

There I am telling some one (*du*) to remind me.

> Erinnerst du mich an die Arbeit!

*-st* and *du* being out it should be:

> Erinner mich an die Arbeit!

Comment: After the revision, it is actually possible to understand the question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3106/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-singular-imperativ-mit-und-ohne-e-am-ende is related.

Comment: After the most recent edit, there are a few statements in your post but I still cannot tell what your question is.

Answer (score 3):

You sure mean e.g.

> Bitte erinnere **mich** an den Brief!

This means *you* should remind **me** about the letter. It's not reflexive.

> Bitte erinnere **dich** an den Brief!

This means *you* should remind **yourself** about the letter. It's reflexive.

Your confusion may come from the fact the reflexive pronouns of the first and second person are **indistinguishable** from the personal pronoun in the accusative and dative case.

---

Consider in contrary:

> Ich erinnere **mich** an den Brief.

This means I remind **myself** about the letter. It's reflexive.

> Ich erinnere **dich** an den Brief.

This means I remind **you** about the letter. Not reflexive.

> Du erinnerst **mich** an den Brief.

This means you remind **me** about the letter. Not reflexive.

> Du erinnerst **dich** an den Brief.

This means you remind **yourself** about the letter. It's reflexive.

If you ponder about this, you could argue German doesn't even have a reflexive pronoun of the first and second person. It's not marking reflexiveness at all but only the person and the accusative case. (For dative case, it's just the same.)

Comment: jmd. an etwas erinnern = to _remind_ sb. of sth.; sich an etw. erinnern = to _remember_ sth.

Comment: Danke. Ich wusste, dass da etwas nicht passte, aber nicht, was genau.

Comment: Keine Ursache. Es ist aber immer noch nicht richtig. Es müsste _remind_ bei den Sätzen 1, 4 und 5 und _remember_ bei den Sätzen 2, 3 und 6 sein, und zwar mit der jeweils richtigen Präposition, die in keinem Falle _about_ lautet. In Anbetracht der Tatsache, dass es im Englischen zwei verschiedene Konzepte für _erinnern_ gibt, sollten Sie vielleicht ein anderes Verb als Beispiel nehmen.

Comment: Genauer: _Bitte erinnere mich an den Brief_ wäre _Please remind me of the letter._ Und _Ich erinnere mich an den Brief_ wäre _I remember the letter._ Da hier aber das Wort _myself_ verschwunden ist, sind die Beispiele ungeeignet, um die Frage des OP zu beantworten.